# validates_inclusion_of always fails on static data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm using rails 3.1.0.rc5 while trying to implement a pseudo enum field.

I am trying to validate the value of a field that is bound to a static list. Unfortunately it always fails validation.

model code>

```
STATUSES = %w( pending active completed )
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUSES, :on => :create, :message => "%{value} must be one of #{STATUSES.join ', '}"
```

form markup>

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Task::STATUSES, @task.status) %>
  </div>
```

unfortunately the validation routine for status always fails. looking at the post data, it contains a value and it is valid.. so i'm not sure what is going on?

i've tried adding the following as well based on some googling

```
def status=(value)
    write_attribute(:status, value.to_s)
  end

  def status
    attributes = attributes_before_type_cast
    if attributes["status"]
      read_attribute(:status).to_sym
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

however, the status= (setter) never seems to get called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell without having a look at your controller but i'm assuming your controller is doing something like:

```
# I'm naming the model User but this would be the name of the model you're using
@user = User.create(params[:user])
```

Your form is going to post something like this:

```
{ :status => 'pending' }
```

When it should be putting the status in the user hash like so:

```
{ :user => { :status => 'pending' } }
```

You'll want to alter your form to post the attributes correctly:

Comment: thank you very much... i was looking at the post data but didn't see the } closing brace before the status field.. it was late =\

this has helped me to fix another issue that i was having too.. thanks!

Comment: just in case anyone else is going to have a select to deal with an associated field.. this seemed to work best for me

<%= collection_select(:task, :assigned_to, User.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select user') %>

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the select tag. You have to use the [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) helper in order to get your setter called when you call User.new(params[:user]) or something like that.